# Does not contain definition for "HasDefaultValue"

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I want to set a default value for a non nullable field in code first.

I have included `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` but I'm still getting

> Does not contain definition for 'HasDefaultValue'

Using EF Core 2.2.6

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Agency>(entity =>
        {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Region)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Agencies)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RegionId)
                    .HasDefaultValue(1)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Agency_Region");
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: are you using `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`? make sure you have  reference of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured the correct syntax. Was assigning the default value at wrong place.

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.RegionId).HasDefaultValue(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

***EF Core 6+***

My issue here was I didn't add this package to my Repository project:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```